# Open app in App Store if App is not installed in Device by Deep Linking in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, deep-linking, url-scheme

My App should have to be open in Device if already installed, by clicking message link.

If my App not installed, it should redirect to Appstore to download the app.

I know URL scheme, but it wont work if app is not installed in the device to redirect to App Store.

I have checked few forums, either we can open app from device if app is already installed else we can open website by clicking that link by using "Universal Linking" which was introduced in iOS 9.

But, I don't want to open my website, if my app not installed in device, I want to navigate the user to App Store.

**My link is from Mail or Message, not from inside my app.**

Can anyone guide me, how to make it possible!

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible without using, at least, a simple web page. Wait for any answer please :)

Comment: This duplicate marking is not exactly correct, though it's close. @LucaD'Alberti is correct: to achieve this sort of flow you do need a simple web page that redirects to the App Store. If you don't want to set up something like this, services like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) are designed to handle it all for you.

Comment: @AlexBauer, i tried to use that SDK, but while initialising the code, its not executing following inside.    let branch: Branch = Branch.getInstance()
    branch.initSessionWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, andRegisterDeepLinkHandler: { params, error in
        if (error == nil) {
            // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked -> was re-directed to this app
            // params will be empty if no data found
            NSLog("params: %@", params.description)
        }
    })
can u guide me?

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper you should create a new question for this, or [submit a ticket to the Branch integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new)

Comment: I found solution!! Now, its working fine!! I used Branch SDK!! Thanks to Branch SDK team!! what a great framework!!

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper It is possible to do same without Branch SDK ? I created apple-app-site-association for Universal link but it is not working. Any idea on this ?

Comment: where can i get branch.io full documentaion?